# Union link rule

Tags: drools, rule

I have problems codify this rule in drools which unites the link to the same destination exists and if the inveso then does the union of the latter also.

```
class Node { 
    List <Link> out;
    List <Link> in;
} 
class Link {
     Source node;
     Target node;
}
```

they are inserted as facts in working memory.

```
example.
A - link1 -> B
A - link2 -> B
A - link3 -> C
C - link4 -> D
B - link5 -> A

result
A - link1 + link2 +link5 -> B
A - link3 -> C
C - link4 -> D
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What kind of C is that ?

Comment: The model is write in java

Comment: Also asked on the Drools user list. Arrgh.

Comment: @Quentin If you don't see what it is, don't call it C. ;-)

Comment: @laune There once was a 'C' tag under this question.

Comment: @Quentin Then "Please remove the "C" tag" might be a better comment.

Comment: @laune indeed. I'll care to make edit-proof comments from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all redundant Link objects and assuming that class Link is declared as

```
class Link {
  Node source;
  Node target;
}
```

(and not as given in the original post), the rule:

```
rule "kill redundant links"
when
    $l1: Link( $s: source, $t: target )
    $l2: Link( this != $l1,
               source == $s && target == $t
               ||
               source == $t && target == $s )
    $n1: Node( out contains $l2 )
    $n2: Node( in contains $l2 )
then
    retract( $l2 );
    modify( $n1 ){ getOut().remove( $l2 ) }
    modify( $n2 ){ getIn().remove( $l2 ) }
end
```

removes all redundant Link facts and updates the `out` and `in` fields of
the `Node`s at either end of these links.